# acro prints singular and plural

Tags: acronyms, acro

I defined an acronym like this:

```
    \DeclareAcronym{LSTM}{
      short = LSTM ,
      long  = long short-term memory,
      long-plural = long short-term memories
    }
```

The problem: using `\acp{LSTM}` prints the singular **and** the plural form (i.e., "*long short-term memorylong short-term memories (LSTMs)*").

What could be the reason for it?

**MVE**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}% provides \capitalisewords
\acsetup{
    list-long-format=\capitalisewords,
      extra-style=comma,
      list-style   = lof,
      list-heading = subsubsection*,
      list-short-format={\bfseries},
    only-used=false,
    list-style = longtable}
    
    \DeclareAcronym{LSTM}{
      short = LSTM ,
      long  = long short-term memory,
      long-plural = long short-term memories
    }

\begin{document}
    \acp{LSTM}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `long-plural-form`, which replaces. `long-plural` appends (e.g., `s`). Manual pp7,8.

Answer (score 1):

The `long-plural` property (and likewise the other plural properties like `short-plural`) should maybe rather be called `long-plural-ending`. Per default it has the value `s` and is appended to the value of `long`. Therefore an acronym defined like this

```
\DeclareAcronym{LSTM}{
  short = LSTM ,
  long  = long short-term memory
}
```

would get the long plural `long short-term memorys`.  In order to get a different form you should do

```
\DeclareAcronym{LSTM}{
  short = LSTM ,
  long  = long short-term memory,
  long-plural-form = long short-term memories
}
```

which would print the long plural as `long short-term memories`.

---

If you instead do

```
\DeclareAcronym{LSTM}{
  short = LSTM ,
  long  = long short-term memory,
  long-plural = long short-term memories
}
```

as in your MWE then `long short-term memories` is appended to `long short-term memory` and leads to `long short-term memorylong short-term memories`.